# How to select using multiple attribute selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable multiple fields in a checkbox survey at the same time. Is it possible to select by multiple classes on same the div? I tried below but its not working. The code works with one class.

```
function surveyInit(){
  $("div[class*='addressLine1', class*='addressLine2'] input"  ).attr('disabled', 'disabled');    
}
```

Comment: Do the classes really _contain_ `addressLine1` or is it _exactly_ `addressLine1`?

Comment: Side note: `.attr("disabled", "disabled")` works, but `.prop("disabled" true)` is simpler, and lets you use `.prop("disabled", false)` to undo it (instead of `.removeAttr("disabled")`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use multiple selectors separated by commas, not put the commas inside the attribute selector.

```
function surveyInit(){
    $("div[class*='addressLine1'] input, div[class*='addressLine2'] input").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Comment: *`*=`* denotes `Attribute Contains Selector` hence `$("div[class*='addressLine']")` should be enough.

Comment: @Rayon That will also match `addressLine3`

Comment: Yeah, my bad. That depends on the use case.

Answer (score -2):

you need comma as seperator and you can youse dot to select class instead of attribute selector

```
function surveyInit(){
 $("div.addressLine1 input,div.addressLine2 input"  ).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

}
```

Comment: Note this is subtly different to the OP. `[class*='addressLine1']` selects any element where the class contains `addressLine1`, your answer selects elements where the class is _exactly_ `addressLine1` - hence my comment for clarification on the question.

Comment: Your comment to OP was not answered so i "assumed" addressLine12 is not desirable i gave other option for exact match to avoid possible bugs.